# Printing certain div is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, printing, datatable, html-table

I am using datables plugin for drawing a table on my web app.

But here is the problem.

I have a print button which calls me this function:

```
function printHTML(clonedDive){
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.contentWindow.onunload = function(){
            $("#submenu").show("fast");
            $(".content-secondary").animate({
                             width: '15%'
                         });

            $(".content-primary").animate({
                             width: '83%'
                         });     
     };
      iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(clonedDive);
      iframe.contentWindow.print();

      document.body.removeChild(iframe); 
}
```

This is how I call this function:

```
printHTML( document.getElementById("results").cloneNode(true));
```

now `results` div looks like this:

```
<div id="results">
<table id="stops" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" >
                <thead>
                    <tr class="even">

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                      <tbody>
                      </tbody>

                     </table>
                     </br>

                     <hr>

                     <p id="title"><b>Map</b></p>
                     <div id="map_find">

                     </div>
</div>
```

So table is working like this: when you click on the row, the row got highlighted and map is shown. So problem is occurring when I click print button.

On the print preview I can see the table but the row is not highlighted and the Google map is not shown. It seems like it is showing me the div that is firstly initialized and there is not highlighted rows and Google maps is not shown.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered changing to use [`@media types`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@media)?

```
@media print
{
  *{
     visibility: hidden;
  }
  #results{
     visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

You can set the visibility of everything you would like to not print with `visibility: hidden` and anything you would like to print with `visibility: visible`.

Then on click you would call:

[`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.print)

**[EXAMPLE WITH MEDIA TYPE](http://jsfiddle.net/MsmVb/)**

**[EXAMPLE WITHOUT MEDIA TYPE](http://jsfiddle.net/aPztQ/)**

Comment: This would go with any other css code. Inside the `head` of the document either `link`ed from an external css file or in the `style` tag

Comment: this is not working, I have tried to put several id's to visible and none is shown

Comment: Would you mind editing your OP with the changes you've made? I added two examples to my post to show you with and without the media type.

Comment: I tried the same code that you wrote and my div is not shown. I can see that is showing a 2 pages but they are empty